# How do I create a master/root schema with normalizr 2?

Tags: javascript, normalizr

Say I have the following schemas and data:

```
const user = new schema.Entity('users')
const video = new schema.Entity('videos', {
  user
})
const comment = new schema.Entity('comments', {
  video
})

// Sample Data
const users = [
  { id: 1, object: "User", name: "User 1" },
  { id: 2, object: "User", name: "User 2" },
]
const videos = [
  { id: 1, object: "Video", user: users[0] },
  { id: 2, object: "Video", user: users[1] },
]
const comments = [
  { id: 1, object: "Comment", video: videos[0] },
  { id: 2, object: "Comment", video: videos[0] },
]
```

How would I setup a `resource` and `resourceList` schema to wrap all my schemas so that in my api calls I would only ever have to reference `resource` or `resourceList` eg:

```
api.videos.list().then(
  // response.data is an array containing multiple videos
  response => normalize(response.data, resourceList)
) 
// entities: { videos: [...], users: [...] }
```

or

```
api.videos.retrieve(videoId).then(
  // response.data is an object containing a single video
  response => normalize(response.data, resource)
)
```

I've tried doing this:

```
const resource = {
  user,
  video,
}

const resourceList = new schema.Array(resource, inferSchema)

function inferSchema({ object: objectName = '' }) {
  return objectName.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + objectName.slice(1)
}
```

But that didn't seem to work.

Comment: What about this didn't work? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: calling `normalize(data: <Array>, list: <ArraySchema>)` didn't give me the entities I was expecting. Maybe `resource` should be `schema.Union({...}, inferSchemaPlural)` and resourceList: `schema.Array(resource)`?

Comment: Can't answer without sample data...

Comment: I provided sample data. It's below the schema entity definitions.